# Docker mysgl-server5.5

Tags: mysql, linux, docker

Запускаю докер контейнер с mysql с хранилищем на хосте

```
docker run --name mysql_1 -v /var/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=passwd -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 -d mysql:5.5
```

Теперь нужно развернуть бэкап базы [по примеру](https://hub.docker.com):

```
docker exec -i mysql_1 sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"passwd"' < databases.sql
```

И собственно `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Кучу вариантов перепробовал, как подключиться теперь к мускулю что бы развернуть бэкап?

Comment: А у вас процесс инициализации базы завершился? В логах есть что-то подобное: `MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.`?

Comment: Вот что влогах
13:11:59  InnoDB: Error: page 694 log sequence number 141284264460
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 141057261580.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.